# Удалённое подключение к Ubuntu server с помощью Putty

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, веб-сервер

Установил Ubuntu server на домашний комп. 
Установил ssh(sudo apt-get ssh). 
На ноутбуке под Windows 10 поставил putty.
Ввёл IP адрес Ubuntu server, логин, пароль. и удачно подключился.

Позже на ноуте сменил точку доступа в интернет и Putty перестал меня пускать в Ubuntu через Ip адрес(**network error connection timed out**). 
В чём причина? Какие настройки нужно сделать в операционке и в модеме? 
Спасибо !

Comment: Какой вы указываете IP? Динамический ли он у вас?

Comment: набираю команду ifconfig. и выписываю адрес 192.168.1.3. Статический адресс ненастраивал.

Comment: Ну так получается вы вписываете адрес локальный, системы Wi-Fi к который вы не подключены.

Comment: мне нужно сделать проброс порта ?

Comment: Вам нужно подключить или две машины к одному wi-fi, или дать серверу статичный Ip, или работать через NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Роутер **GR-534W**.
В опции **Inernet-Lan-Statically Assigned** указал **Mac** и **Ip** моего **Ubuntu servera** для того чтобы роутер не менял адрес и он оставался статическим.

В опции **Firewall-Virtual Server Settings** указал также **Ip** адрес servera и **Port Range 22-22**. 
Протоколы **TCP** и **UDP**.

Включил **Ip** **forwarding** в **Ubuntu** по [этой](http://www.ithowto.ru/75-kak-vklyuchit-ip-forwarding-v-linux.html) статье.

После этих изменений открылся 22 порт и удалось подключится к Ubuntu server через внешний IP адрес и 22 порт.

Answer (score -1):

1 вам надо у провайдера подключить статический ip  адрес чтобы подключаться из интернета.
2 вам надо проброска порты на роутера.